# Quantity like correlation

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

I want to calculate this sort of quantity, $f()$, for my data. $x$ and $y$ are time series.

$f$ behaves like a pseudo-correlation, but is different in the sense that even if the values jump up and down, their $f$ is still weakly positive, and it becomes negative if the values alternate sign(frequently).

Here is the rough application context. Suppose in real time we encounter 2 types of objects: blues and reds, each of which is of different size. I want to measure the temporal clustering of these objects. The change of color(i.e. the change of sign) is more heavily-weighted than the change of quantity. If I see 2 consecutive blue objects of radically different size, I want to say that there is still some clustering, but not too much, while when I see 2 large objects of different color, I want to say there's 'anti-clustering'.

Comment: The second and third bullet points make sense only for *numbers*, not arrays, because arrays can have various signs. What is the "one exception" to which you refer?

Comment: Correct, but I meant sort of at intuitive level.

The exception is that for example, if you have the array
[1,100,1,100], the autocorrelation will be negative, because the size jumps up at down, while here I want it to be weakly positive.

Comment: The difficulty here is that because those bullets don't make sense as stated, it is hard to understand what your intuition is. Even the connection between a function of two arrays $x$ and $y$ with a pseudo-autocorrelation is murky. Do you perhaps intend $x$ and $y$ to be lagged versions of the same time series?  (If indeed you are concerned with time series, it would help to apply the [tag:time-series] tag or at least mention these are time series in the question.)

Comment: Editted. I think you get the idea what I mean, so feel free to help me with the wording of the original question.

Comment: I wish I could help, but I truly am uncertain about what you are looking for. Without any context at all I have no basis to make guesses.  Could you perhaps explain in more general terms what the point of such a construction would be?  What would $f$ represent and how would it be used?

Comment: Here is the rough application context. Suppose in real time we encounter 2 types of objects: blues and reds, each of which is of different size. I want to measure the temporal clustering of these objects. The change of color(i.e. the change of sign) is more heavily-weighted than the change of quantity. If I see 2 consecutive blue objects of radically different size, I want to say that there is still some clustering, but not too much, while when I see 2 large objects of different color, I want to say there's 'anti-clustering'.

Comment: That is helpful: please include your explanation in the question.  I think then people might be able to apprehend your intentions and perhaps formulate useful approaches for your consideration.